# OpenLayer Popups for markers imported from google spreadsheet

Tags: vector, dictionary, popup, openlayers

I'm looking for a way to use framecloud type popup with my current setup. Unfortunately all my attempts have either not worked or will only work on the most recently placed maker.

In the course of trying to get it to work I have converted my original script from using Markers to using Vectors to placing the marker points (as I've seen that it's easier to customize vectors than markers.)

Now which ever one I can get to work I'll use, but after working on this for a few days I'm at my wits end and need a helping hand in the right direction.

My points are pulled from a google spreadsheet using tabletop.js. The feature is working how I wish it to, with the markers being placed on their respective layer based on a field I called 'type'.
While I have a feeling that might have been the source of my problem with the Markers type layer, I'm not sure how to fix it.

You can view the coding through these pages

(Links removed due to location change.)

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work. For anyone in a similar situation here's my final code for the layers. I did change the names of the layers from what they are originally and blacked out the spreadsheet I used, but the changes should be noticeable.

```
//
//// Set 'Markers'
//
            var iconMarker = {externalGraphic: 'http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 21, graphicWidth: 16};
            var iconGeo = {externalGraphic: './images/fortress.jpg', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 25};
            var iconAero = {externalGraphic: './images/aeropolae.jpg', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 25}; // Image is the creation of DriveByArtist: http://drivebyartist.deviantart.com/

            var vector1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("1");
            var vector2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("2");
            var vector3 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("3");


// Pulls map info from Spreadsheet
//*
        Tabletop.init({
          key: 'http://xxxxxxxxxx', //Spreadsheet URL goes here
          callback: function(data, tabletop) { 
            var i,
                dataLength = data.length;

            for (i=0; i<dataLength; i++) { //following are variables from the spreadsheet
                locName = data[i].name;
                locLon = data[i].long;
                locLat = data[i].lat;
                locInfo = data[i].info;
                locType = data[i].type; // Contains the following string in the cell, which provides a pre-determined output based on provided information in the spreadsheet: =ARRAYFORMULA("<h2>"&B2:B&"</h2><b>"&G2:G&"</b><br /> "&C2:C&", "&D2:D&"<br />"&E2:E&if(ISTEXT(F2:F),"<br /><a target='_blank' href='"&F2:F&"'>Read More...</a>",""))

                locLonLat= new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(locLon, locLat);

               switch(locType)
                {
                case "Geopolae":
                     feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                     locLonLat,
                     {description:locInfo},
                     iconGeo);
                    vector1.addFeatures(feature);        
                  break;
                case "POI":
                  feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                     locLonLat,
                     {description:locInfo},
                     iconMarker);
                    vector2.addFeatures(feature);             
                  break;
                case "Aeropolae":
                  feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                     locLonLat,
                     {description:locInfo},
                     iconAero);
                    vector3.addFeatures(feature);             
                  break;  
                }

              }
          },
          simpleSheet: true 
        });             

            map.addLayers([vector1, vector2, vector3]);

            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

        //Add a selector control to the vectorLayer with popup functions
        var controls = {
          selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(Array(vector1, vector2, vector3), { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
        };

        function createPopup(feature) {
          feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
              feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
              null,
              '<div class="markerContent">'+feature.attributes.description+'</div>',
              null,
              true,
              function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
          );
          feature.popup.autoSize = true;
          feature.popup.minSize = new OpenLayers.Size(400,100);
          feature.popup.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(400,800);
          feature.popup.fixedRelativePosition = true;
          feature.popup.overflow ="auto";
          //feature.popup.closeOnMove = true;
          map.addPopup(feature.popup);
        }

        function destroyPopup(feature) {
          feature.popup.destroy();
          feature.popup = null;
        }

        map.addControl(controls['selector']);
        controls['selector'].activate();

        }
```